# Indesign: remove anchored objects in Table of Contents

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

Below is a heading on page 10 starting by an anchored object

[image]

When I create my ToC (below), this anchored object is still there. Any idea to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Use Grep find/change to remove anchored objects in your Toc. Find ~a (anchored object marker), replace by nothing.
Pros: super fast
Cons: You need to redo it every time you update the TOC

**Solution 2:**
If not done already, create an object style and apply it to all your anchored objects. It's not absolutely necessary, but will give you better control over all anchored objects, so I recommend you don't skip this step.
Then, go to object style options > anchored object options.
Change position from "inline" to "custom" and adjust position in order to get the same layout than initially.  You'll probably have to make a few more adjustments (text warp, left indent, space before...).
The trick is than Indesign kinda "separate" anchored object from text paragraph when the objects aren't positioned "inline". Why? I don't know ^^ but it results that custom positioned objects do not show in Table of contents.
Pros: No need to redo anything while updating TOC. Anchored objects will always be ignored.
Cons: Much more time consuming method than solution 1

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[I found a solution on Adobe Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2152017)

```
Find / Change in the Table of Contents.
Find ^a
Change to [nothing—keep blank]
Be sure to Search within the Story or Selection, whichever makes more sense. 
Only Search in the TOC, not the document.
```

Not perfect according to me because not automatic but at least it works.
Any other idea appreciated...